How to initialize values in shared memory
I am cross-compiling on a Ubuntu 24.04 host for a Raspberry Pi Zero2 W. I want to be able to access data for a device on the i2c bus not only from multiple instances in the same program but also from different processes. So, I believe I need to use shared memory and I need a lock in that shared memory so only 1 instance of 1 process can communicate with the device at a time.
So, I have the following:
int shmem_fd = shm_open(shmem_fname.c_str(), O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666);
  if (shmem_fd != -1) {
    /*
     * This is the first access so size the shared memory, mmap it and initialize the data
     */
    int result = ftruncate(shmem_fd, sizeof(Lps22DeviceData));
    device_data_ = static_cast<Lps22DeviceData*>(mmap(NULL, sizeof(Lps22DeviceData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmem_fd, 0));


My question is how do I initialize the lps22DeviceData in the mmap ?
It is a data only class.
class Lps22DeviceData {
 public:
  std::recursive_mutex lock_ = {};
  uint64_t read_total_ = 0;
  bool initialized = false;
  int16_t temperature_measurement_ = 0;
  time_point<system_clock> temperature_measurement_system_time_;
  time_point<steady_clock> temperature_measurement_steady_time_;
  milliseconds temperature_response_time;

  int32_t pressure_measurement_ = 0;
  time_point<system_clock> pressure_measurement_system_time_;
  time_point<steady_clock> pressure_measurement_steady_time_;
  milliseconds pressure_response_time;
};

Most of them are simple integers or time values that I can just assign to some initial values. But, I haven't figured out how to get the lock_ initialized.
    device_data_->read_total_ = 0;
    device_data_->initialized = false;
    device_data_->temperature_measurement_ = 0;
    device_data_->temperature_measurement_system_time_ = system_clock::now();
    device_data_->temperature_measurement_steady_time_ = steady_clock::now();
    device_data_->temperature_response_time = milliseconds(0);

    device_data_->pressure_measurement_ = 0;
    device_data_->pressure_measurement_system_time_ = system_clock::now();
    device_data_->pressure_measurement_steady_time_ = steady_clock::now();
    device_data_->pressure_response_time = milliseconds(0);
    device_data_->initialized = true;

I tried:
device_data_->lock_ = {};

Which seems to work in the class definition when I had this working for multiple instances in one process:
[build] /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/src/lib/devices/i2c/lps22.cpp: In constructor ‘Lps22::Lps22(I2cBus, uint8_t)’:
[build] /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/src/lib/devices/i2c/lps22.cpp:49:28: error: use of deleted function ‘std::recursive_mutex& std::recursive_mutex::operator=(const std::recursive_mutex&)’
[build]    49 |     device_data_->lock_ = {};

How do I initialize a device_data_->lock_ that ends up inside the mmap so that all processes see the lock?
Thanks

This is not going to be sufficient. Process A checks the lock and sees it can use the device. At the exact same time in another core Process B checks the lock and sees it can use the device. Process A and Process B then both set the flag to prevent further entrants, but you already have one more entrant than is acceptable. You will also have a problem with a process that crashes while the flag is set.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html may be of assistance.

I see your points. I did find out about something called a "placement new" that does allow you to define where an object gets defined. So "new (device_data_) LpsDeviceData;" does at least pass the compiler. But I'll have to take your points into consideration. Thanks

Also useful to you: Boost Interprocess

Side note: I did a slight misread earlier. The real sin here is recursive_mutex is not guaranteed to work across processes. It only officially works intraprocess, but might work as you intend on some platforms. Linux seems to be a good candidate for Might Working (typically implemented atop pthread which allows this behaviour) but Boost will pretty much always work.

Almost everything in Linux is a file, including shared memory. What looks like you need here is a pipe that would pass messages between processes. That's also a file, but it has a mechanism of guaranteeing two point communication without data races.

I would suggest having one process communicate with sensors via I2C and communicating with other processes via a pipe.

Trying to serialize access to a physical device through a lock (atomic/mutex/whatever) in a shm block is a very bad idea. What if the process crashes while holding the lock ? You will have to manually clean the shm block and restart it... Consider flock, ipc semaphores or any other mean is certainly safer, cleaner and simpler.
